# Validating JSON files on Ubuntu from the command line

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, json, validation

I'm looking for an offline command line program that can validate JSON files on Ubuntu: I have a folder containing a list of JSON files, some possibly corrupted, so I would have to have the list of corrupted JSON files.

Comment: Are you by any chance running PHP on that Ubuntu machine? If so, and you only want to separate the wheat from the chaff: `for json in folder/*; do echo $json; php -r "\$foo=json_decode(file_get_contents('$json'));"; done` This will echo all file names followed by errors for that file ***if there are any*** – otherwise the filename only. Adjust for perfection: `for json in folder/*; do php -r "if ( ! \$foo=json_decode(file_get_contents('$json')) ) echo \"$json has errors\n\";"; done`, which would only list the corrupted files.

Comment: @Izzy Thanks, I am running PHP on some machine, so that works too :) You're welcome to post it as an answer.

Comment: Done, Franck – including an explanation for the not-so-techy who still want to try it :) Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

Without the need for a specific application, if you just want to separate the wheat from the chaff, and have PHP installed on the Linux machine, you can use a simple one-liner for this:

```
for json in folder/*; do php -r "if ( ! \$foo=json_decode(file_get_contents('$json')) ) echo \"$json\n\";"; done
```

This would list all *broken* `.json` files in the directory named `folder`. Take out the exlamation mark (`!`) to only list the `.json` files which are fine.

It might well be PHP spits out some additional error message here. If that happens, just re-direct error output (STDERR) to the machine's black hole (`/dev/null`):

```
for json in folder/*; do php -r "if ( ! \$foo=json_decode(file_get_contents('$json')) ) echo \"$json\n\";" 2>/dev/null; done
```

---

#### TL;DR – a short explanation of what that one-liner does

- `for json in folder/*; do […] done`: loop over all `.json` files in the given location. On each iteration, store the file name into a variable named `$json`.
- `php -r`: invoke the PHP executable. The `-r` parameter tells it to (r)un a command instead of expecting a file. The command must directly follow this, separated by white-space.
- `"[…]"`: using double-quotes, we can easier integrate shell variables. The price is we have to escape all `$` signs belonging to PHP variables.
- `\$foo`: see previous point, we need to escape the `$` here.
- `$foo=json_decode(file_get_contents('$json'))`: have PHP reading the file (`file_get_contents`; the `$json` here is our Bash variable from the first bullet-point), then convert the JSON to a PHP object (`json_decode`). We don't want to see the result, so we assign it to a variable (`$foo` in my example).
  If decoding was successful, the assignment will return `TRUE`, otherwise `FALSE` – which is why we can use this construction as our "if condition".
- `if ( […] ) echo \"$json\n\";"`: only write the file name (this again is our Bash variable here) to the console if our condition is met – to "separate the wheat from the chaff", as I've put it initially. As usual in PHP, the command needs to be terminated by a semi-colon (`;`). Also note that I needed to escape the double-quotes here, so our "outer Shell wrapper" doesn't end prematurely. I needed the double-quotes, so `\n` is interpreted as "new line" – with single-quotes, it would print a literal `\n` instead.
- `2>/dev/null`: Redirect error output (STDERR) to the "black hole" (i.e. don't show any errors if they occur). Our `echo` commands go to STDOUT, and thus are not affected by this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jsonlint](https://github.com/zaach/jsonlint):

- CLI
- open source (written in JavaScript)
- check whether file(s) are valid:

Example:

```
# Install
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs npm
sudo npm install jsonlint -g
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node # to avoid "/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory" error
jsonlint -qc *.json

# Use
ubuntu@pm:~/pubmed/pubmed$ jsonlint --compact --validate *.json
my_file_bad.json: line 279916, col 18, found: 'EOF' - expected: 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['.
ubuntu@pm:~/pubmed/pubmed$
```

Useful options:

```
   -c, --compact            compact error display
   -V, --validate           a JSON schema to use for validation
```